# Is java.util a package or a library?

Tags: java

I am confused if java.util is a  package or a library.What is the difference between a package and library?

Comment: Definitely a package, part of a library (the standard one): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html

Comment: A library is a general purpose term which means *one or more classes providing a set of functions*. Library and packages are two different things.

Comment: It's pretty much both.

Comment: What is the relevance to you? Why do you bring this up? I'm sure you have seen people refer to the "java.util library". That would be loose usage but as long as you understand what it means, what's the issue?

Comment: Understanding is never bad. Why so many questions asking why he is interested in understanding it?

Comment: @skypjack because understanding why a person asks a question is also never bad, it helps to make the question more specific and less chance of being a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html), `java.util` is a package and part of Java class library:

> **A package is a namespace that organizes a set of related classes and
>   interfaces.**
>   ...
>   The Java platform provides an enormous **class library
>   (a set of packages)** suitable for use in your own applications. This
>   library is known as the "Application Programming Interface", or "API"
>   for short.

Related questions:

1. [Is there a difference between packages in Java and libraries in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962148/is-there-a-difference-between-packages-in-java-and-libraries-in-c)
2. [Class vs package vs module vs component vs container vs service vs platform in Java world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157377/class-vs-package-vs-module-vs-component-vs-container-vs-service-vs-platform-in-j)